# ng2-bootstrap datepicker div being created on button click. How to hide it if the user clicks outside of the div?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using an ng2-datepicker to get a user's date of birth when registering as a new user.  Since the requirement is to have it as a popup, I have the datepicker in a `div` that gets rendered whenever the user clicks a button.  Here's what the datepicker template looks like:

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;" *ngIf="showDatepicker">
    <datepicker name="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="dateModel" [showWeeks]="false" [maxDate]="maxDate" (selectionDone)="hidePopup($event)"></datepicker>
</div>
```

This works great, because whenever they pick a date, we run the `hidePopup` function, which sets the date and hides the popup.

However, we have a new requirement that any time the user clicks or focuses on anything other than the popup, we need to hide the popup.

My question is how to, in an angular2 application, set some sort of eventhandler when the popup shows that will hide the popup if anything OTHER than the popup is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me:

**templete.html**

`<div class="col-md-9" #datepickerE>
<input type="text" class="form-control" (focus)="isShowDatepicker = true">
<div class="popover-datepicker" *ngIf="isShowDatepicker">
<datepicker formControlName="shippingDate" [minDate]="currentDate" [showWeeks]="true" [dateDisabled]="dateDisabled" 
 (selectionDone)="isShowDatepicker = false"></datepicker>
</div>`

**component.ts**

`@Component({`

`selector: 'my-form',`

`host: {`

`'(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',`

`},`

`templateUrl: './templete.html',`

`})`

`export class MaterialForm implements OnInit {`

`@ViewChild("datepickerE") datepickerE: ElementRef;`

`public isShowDatepicker: boolean = false;`

`onClick(event) {`

`if (!this.datepickerE.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {`

`this.isShowDatepicker = false;`

`}`

`}`

`}`